# Executing powershell command under cmd and INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am trying to execute the following powershell commands from `CMD`, for example:

```
powershell Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver 

powershell Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver > test.txt
```

which both work correctly.

But when I do a query, for example:

```
powershell (Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver | where {$_.location -like "*PCI bus 0, device 22, function 0*"}).DeviceName
```

I am getting this message the cause of which I can not pin down:

> INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)

Comment: What happens if your query doesn't have any `*` in it - just a straight-up string match?

Comment: Any reason you're using CMD and not PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work for me (I was seeing the same error as you originally):

```
powershell -command "(Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver | where {$_.location -like '*PCI bus 0, device 22, function 0*'}).DeviceName"
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement the existing answers with **general guidelines** for **passing commands to `powershell.exe` from `cmd.exe`** (a Command Prompt):

- **Enclose the entire PowerShell command in `"..."`** (double quotes).

  - This protects its contents from unwanted up-front interpretation by `cmd.exe` - as happened with `|` in this case, as explained in [aschipfl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43504363/45375).
  - However, `cmd.exe`-style environment-variable references (e.g., `%USERNAME%`) are *still* expanded.
- For **quoting that is *embedded*** in the PowerShell command:

  - **Use `'...'` (single quotes) where feasible**; this is what [Mark Wragg's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43496001/45375) does, but it is only an option if the quoted string is meant to be a *literal* (doesn't contain variable references or subexpressions).
  - **If you do need embedded `"..."`, escape it as `\"...\"`**

    - Note that while *inside* PowerShell it is the  `` ` `` (backtick) that serves as the escape character, when passing strings *from the outside* PowerShell requires `\`.

---

**Simplified examples (run from `cmd.exe`):**

<sup>Note that passing a command without a parameter name implies the `-Command` parameter; run `powershell -?` to see the command-line syntax.

You may also want to use `-NoProfile` so that the user profile isn't loaded every time.</sup>

Commands that don't need embedded quoting - simply double-quote:

```
 powershell -noprofile "get-date"
 powershell -noprofile "(get-date).Date"
 powershell -noprofile "get-date | get-member"
```

Commands with embedded quoting - use `'...'` or `\"...\"`:

```
 powershell -noprofile "(get-date).Year -like '*17'"
 powershell -noprofile "$v=17; (get-date).Year -like \"*$v\""
```

Commands that incorporate the value of a `cmd.exe` environment variable:

```
 :: # Nothing special to do: cmd.exe expands the reference irrespective of quoting.
 set "v=17"
 powershell -noprofile "(get-date).Year -like '*%v%'"

 :: # More robust variant that passes the value as an argument to a script block.
 set "v=17"
 powershell -noprofile ". { param($v) (get-date).Year -like \"*$v\" }" "%v%"
```

---

#### Optional reading: calling `powershell` from POSIX-like shells such as `bash`:

The above rules apply analogously, except that **you'll typically use `'...'` (single quotes)** to enclose the entire PowerShell command, which categorically prevents up-front interpretation by the shell.

Using `"..."` is an option if up-front expansions of shell-variable references and command substitutions are explicitly desired, but the potential for confusion is great, because both POSIX-like shells and PowerShell use sigil `$` to refer to variables - it may not be obvious what is expanded when.

POSIX-like shells categorically do not support embedding `'` instances in side `'...'` strings, which necessitates a somewhat awkward workaround (see below).

**Simplified examples (run from a POSIX-like shell such as `bash`):**

Commands that don't need embedded quoting - simply single-quote:

```
 powershell -noprofile 'get-date'
 powershell -noprofile '(get-date).Date'
 powershell -noprofile 'get-date | get-member'
```

Commands with embedded quoting - replace embedded `'` instances with `'\''` (sic) and use embedded `"` as-is:

```
 powershell -noprofile '(get-date).Year -like '\''*17'\'''
 powershell -noprofile '$v=17; (get-date).Year -like "*$v"'
```

Commands that incorporate the value of a shell/environment variable:

```
 # By using a double-quoted string, the shell expands $v up front.
 v=17
 powershell -noprofile "(get-date).Year -like '*$v'"

 # It gets trickier if you want to reference PS variables too.
 # Note how the PS variable's $ is \-escaped so that the shell doesn't interpret it.
 v=$HOME
 powershell -noprofile "\$HOME -eq '$v'"

 # More robust variant that passes the value as an argument to a script block.
 v=17
 powershell -noprofile '. { param($v) (get-date).Year -like "*$v" }' "$v"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the pipe character `|` is the problem here, because `cmd` tries to process it.
Simply escape it by preceding with `^`:

```cmd
powershell (Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver ^| where {$_.location -like "*PCI bus 0, device 22, function 0*"}).DeviceName
```

If this code is used within a parenthesised block of code in `cmd`, you may need to escape the closing `)` as well (the opening `(` can be escaped too, but there is no need):

```cmd
powershell ^(Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver ^| where {$_.location -like "*PCI bus 0, device 22, function 0*"}^).DeviceName
```

Comment: The `|` is one problem, but there is another: the `"` chars. are removed and must therefore be escaped as `\"`.